# Ubuntu 18.04 :Convert command in Imagemagick not responding

Tags: bash, imagemagick, ubuntu-18.04

[edit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGO8.jpg)I have installed imagemagick in my Ubuntu 18.04 system. When I type the convert command (eg convert -help, convert -version) in my system it is not responding. It is not showing any error it is  behaving like as it is waiting for some input.I tried installing new version of Imagemagick but still the convert command is not working.Other commands related to imagemagick like display are working fine. Can anybody tell me why my convert command is not responding

Comment: Possibly a clash with another `convert` command? `strings $(type -p convert) ` should help you confirm this (several instances of `Magick` in IM's `convert` command). Recent versions of IM now use `magick convert` because of this.

Comment: If you run `type convert` it will tell you exactly what will be run when you run `convert`. Click [edit] and add that output to your question. You could try renaming that to `convert.22-APR-2022` so it no longer exists. Then uninstall and reinstall **ImageMagick** and see what happens.